# How to replace last character in a string with white space in the end

Tags: java, regex, whitespace, trim

I have this kind of scenario in java, the last character `:` or `-` in a string should be replaced with "".

Example:

```
String value = "data - ";

String value2 = "data :";

value.replaceAll("[-:]$","");

value2.replaceAll("[:-]$","");

System.out.println(value);

System.out.println(value2);
```

Output:

```
data -

data
```

I think the whitespace treated as the last character and does not match the regex provide, can someone help me with this scenarion? thank you.

Comment: `value.replaceFirst("\\s*[-:]\\s*$","");`

Comment: plus 1 para sa grad pic :) nice one. Before you replace trim the spaces first so you can eliminate the spaces

Comment: @Katana I think your solution is a redundant process because after replacing the character trimming will follow.

Comment: `String` is immutable object in Java. The original value will not be changed by invoking `replaceAll()` method. The `replaceAll()` method will return a new instance  of `String`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thank you!

Comment: @rjre11211994 yah your right. you can perform in one process using regex the first comment is correct

Comment: @rjre11211994 v r hpy 2 hlp u. +1 fr ur atmpts.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static String strip(String s) {
    if (s.endsWith(":") || s.endsWith("-")){
        s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `value.trim()` to remove any extra spaces.

Comment: yes trimming will follow after replacement, thanks for reminding